# Proof check: limit of product is equal to product of limits

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to check my proof of the following statement:

> if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = L_1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x) = L_2$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}(f \cdot g)(x) = L_1L_2$

I can't find any proof that is similar to mine, so I am curious whether my proof is valid.

*Proof.* Fix $\epsilon > 0 $. Let $\delta_1, \delta_2 > 0$ be such that $$0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L_1| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$$ and $$0 < |x-a| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x) - L_2| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$$ Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$. Then for any $x$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, we have \begin{align} |f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2| &\leq |f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2| + |- f(x)L_2 - L_1g(x) + 2L_1L_2| \\ &\leq |f(x) - L_1||g(x) - L_2| \qquad \text{(by triangle inequality)} \\ &< \epsilon \qquad \square\end{align}

I would appreciate any comment on this proof, thanks in advance.

Edit: For the second $\leq$ I used the following reasoning:
\begin{align} |f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2| + |- f(x)L_2 - L_1g(x) + 2L_1L_2| &\leq |(f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2) + (- f(x)L_2 - L_1g(x) + 2L_1L_2)| \\ &= |f(x)g(x) - f(x)L_2 - L_1g(x) + L_1L_2| \\ &= |(f(x) - L_1)(g(x) - L_2)| \\ &= |f(x) - L_1||g(x) - L_2| \\ &< \sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{\epsilon} \\ &= \epsilon \end{align}

Comment: In the final calculation, the second $\le$ step seems unjustified to me.

Comment: @GregMartin Hi Greg, thanks for your feedback. I edited my question to include my reasoning for the second $\leq$. Does it make sense?

Comment: I've never seen an epsilon-delta proof using a $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ bound on errors, for this or anything else. The usual approach uses $fg-L_1L_2=f(g-L_2)+(f-L_1)L_2$ to prove $\epsilon_i<\min\left\{1,\,\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|L_{3-i}|)}\right\}$ for $i\in\{1,\,2\}$ suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately, your proof is invalid.**

The key point is that you use what you call "triangle inequality" the wrong way around. For numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, the triangle inequality states that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$. This is true. However, you use the converse statement, namely that $|a| + |b| \leq |a+b|$. This is not always true. For example, take $a=1$, $b=-1$. The left-hand side is $|1|+|-1| = 1+1 = 2$, while the right-hand side is $|1+(-1)|=|0|=0$.